# pgfplots Limits Ranges strange behaviour

Tags: pgfplots

When I do a plot with pgfplots and define Limits Ranges (`xmin` etc.) and additionally try to draw in the coordinate system, I have to add the limit ranges when using relative coordinates. Am I doing something wrong?

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.11}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
   x = 0.1cm,
   y = 0.1cm,
   domain = 0:60,
   axis lines=center,
   xmin = -9,
   xmax = 69,
   ymin = -9,
   ymax = 49,
]
\addplot {40*0.9772^x};
\draw (0,20) -- (20,20);
\draw [red] (20,20) -- ++(0,-20);
\draw [green] (20,20) -- ++(-9,-29);
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: It work fine with `\draw [red] (20,20) -- ++(0cm,-2cm);`
`\draw [green] (20,20) -- ++(2cm,-2cm);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The default coordinate system is `axis cs` in environment `axis`. It can be used for *absolute* coordinates. It is not suitable for relative coordinates, because the origin can be different from `(0pt, 0pt)`. In the case of the example it is different and you would have to subtract the real origin. An easier way is using the `axis direction cs`, which is intended for *relative* coordinates:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.11}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
   x = 0.1cm,
   y = 0.1cm,
   domain = 0:60,
   axis lines=center,
   xmin = -9,
   xmax = 69,
   ymin = -9,
   ymax = 49,
]
\addplot {40*0.9772^x};
\draw (0,20) -- (20,20);
\draw [red] (20,20) -- ++(axis direction cs:0,-20);
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]